# Search for specific values and use them to construct a new variable

Tags: r, dplyr

I observe a person saving more and more money over time. Once he has bought something with this money, I can ovserve how much he spent for this purchase. Now I want to create a new variable indicating how far away / close / above he was at a given point in time from making that purchase. I observe multiple purchases for some people, but for others no purchase (...in this case, I want to use the mean of all spendings of other people to indicate distance to purchase goal.

Example dataset:

```
da1 <- data.frame(person_id = c(1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3), week=c(1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4), money = c(100,120,160,80,20,40,60,80,10,6,30,20))

da1
   person_id week money
1          1    1   100
2          1    2   120
3          1    3   160
4          1    4    80
5          2    1    20
6          2    2    40
7          2    3    60
8          2    4    80
9          3    1    10
10         3    2     6
11         3    3    30
12         3    4    20
```

This is the expected output. The purchase_distance shows the computation I need to make.

```
da2 <- data.frame(person_id = c(1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3), week=c(1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4), money = c(100,120,160,80,20,40,60,80,10,6,30,20), purchase_distance = c(100/80, 120/80,160/80,80/80,20/mean(c(80,10,4)), 40/31,60/31,80/31,10/4,6/4,30/10,20/10))

da2
   person_id week money purchase_distance
1          1    1   100              1.25
2          1    2   120              1.50
3          1    3   160              2.00
4          1    4    80              1.00
5          2    1    20              0.64
6          2    2    40              1.29
7          2    3    60              1.94
8          2    4    80              2.58
9          3    1    10              2.50
10         3    2     6              1.50
11         3    3    30              3.00
12         3    4    20              2.00
```

This is what I have tried, but it doesn't work and this way coded, it cannot recognize multiple purchases per person...

```
da3 = group_by(da1, person_id) %>%
    mutate(change_in_money = money-lag(money)) %>%
    group_by(person_id, week) %>%
    mutate(purchase_distance = money/abs(max(change_in_money)))

da3
# A tibble: 12 x 5
# Groups:   person_id, week [12]
   person_id  week money change_in_money purchase_distance
       <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>           <dbl>             <dbl>
 1         1     1   100              NA             NA   
 2         1     2   120              20              6   
 3         1     3   160              40              4   
 4         1     4    80             -80              1   
 5         2     1    20              NA             NA   
 6         2     2    40              20              2   
 7         2     3    60              20              3   
 8         2     4    80              20              4   
 9         3     1    10              NA             NA   
10         3     2     6              -4              1.5 
11         3     3    30              24              1.25
12         3     4    20             -10              2
```

Answer (score 2):

```
da1 %>%
  group_by(person_id) %>%
  mutate(
    diff = money-lag(money),
    target = ifelse(diff < 0, diff, NA) 
  ) %>%
  tidyr::fill(target, .direction = "up") %>% 
  ungroup() %>%
  mutate(
    target = coalesce(target, mean(diff[diff < 0], na.rm = TRUE)),
    purchase_distance = money / abs(target)
  )
# # A tibble: 12 x 6
#    person_id  week money  diff target purchase_distance
#        <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl>             <dbl>
#  1         1     1   100    NA  -80               1.25 
#  2         1     2   120    20  -80               1.5  
#  3         1     3   160    40  -80               2    
#  4         1     4    80   -80  -80               1    
#  5         2     1    20    NA  -31.3             0.638
#  6         2     2    40    20  -31.3             1.28 
#  7         2     3    60    20  -31.3             1.91 
#  8         2     4    80    20  -31.3             2.55 
#  9         3     1    10    NA   -4               2.5  
# 10         3     2     6    -4   -4               1.5  
# 11         3     3    30    24  -10               3    
# 12         3     4    20   -10  -10               2
```

In your sample data, all IDs end with a purchase. If that's not the case in your real data you may want to use that ID's last purchase as the target for the next (unobserved) purchase rather than the global mean. To do that, change the `fill` direction to `"updown"`.

Comment: Absolutely awsome, thank you so much! The comment about changing the fill direction is in fact quite important for my data, great job!

Comment: Trying to use the "updown" direction, R tells me that 'arg' should be one of “down”, “up”. What is happening?

Comment: Maybe you have an old version of `tidyr`? It works fine for me. Try updating your packages. If you still have trouble, you can do it with 2 `fill`s, `tidyr::fill(target, .direction = "up") %>% tidyr::fill(target, .direction = "down")`.